# Japan's Maglev Train propulsion and guidance system

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

Above image is taken from Japan's Maglev Train youtube video by Lesics at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjwF-STGtfE&t=585s).

If the electromagnets along the two walls used for guidance of the train (So that it does not hit the walls)  is made up of iron core, **wouldnt** the train which is represented by the bar magnet **(in this case the train leans to the right as shown in image)** be attracted to the iron core attached to the walls and cause an imbalance which means it will hit the walls? Or is it that the propulsion and the guidance electromagnets are made up of pure copper coil (non-magnetic) without the iron core so that the train does not stick on the side of the walls? It's pretty counter-intuitive if you were to think about it.

Comment: They appear to be inducing current through the coils via changes in magnetic field caused by movement  of the bar magnet.  The current in turn magnetizes the iron cores, causing them to repel the bar magnet.  If that's what it is, a slow enough approach should be able to hit the walls, but if it's slow, they might counteract in some other way?